# reactstrap navbar dropdown doesnt shift right

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

```
import {Navbar, NavbarBrand,NavbarToggler, Nav,NavItem, NavLink, UncontrolledDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownItem, DropdownMenu, Collapse} from 'reactstrap'
```

```
<Navbar color='dark' dark expand='md'>
<NavbarBrand>
      My blog

 </NavbarBrand>
<NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle}/>

<Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
     <Nav className='mr-auto' navbar>
              <NavItem>
             <NavLink href="/">
                       link
             </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
    </Nav>
<UncontrolledDropdown>
      <DropdownToggle nav caret>
      options
       </DropdownToggle>
     <DropdownMenu right>
            <DropdownItem>
             Option 1
             </DropdownItem>
             <DropdownItem>
             login
             </DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />
               <DropdownItem>
                 logout
              </DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
 </UncontrolledDropdown>
 </Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

In this navbar I have `<DropdownMenu right>` and yet it stays on the left side
[image]

I am new to this and thus am clueless about how to solve this. Can I please get some help?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class `ml-auto` to `UncontrolledDropdown` component.

```
<UncontrolledDropdown className="ml-auto">
```

Comment: It still didn't change.

Comment: Try `<Nav className='ml-auto' navbar>` instead of `<Nav className='mr-auto' navbar>`

Comment: Changed it, but it still didnt shift right. I'm sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: Please check [this](https://6-4-0--reactstrap.netlify.app/components/navbar/).

Comment: I removed my whole code and just copy-pasted theirs, and yet it's still on the left.